# Semantic Logging using ETW with Custom Keywords not logging

Tags: .net-4.5, etw, semantic-logging

I am trying to use .Net 4.5, Semantic Logging (SLAB) EventSource, to create events with custom keywords.  I would like to use Out-of-Process, and use the keywords to steer events to logfiles or SQL.  I have used EventSourceAnalyzer against this class in a separate test, and no exceptions.

I can "steer" the events to different sinks by using different "EventLevel", but I would prefer to route with custom keywords.

Here is the class --

```
 public class XYZWebLog : EventSource
{
    public class Keywords
    {
        public const EventKeywords Login = (EventKeywords)2;
        public const EventKeywords Billing = (EventKeywords)4;
    }

    [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Login)]
    public void SuccessfulLogin(string loginId) { WriteEvent(1, loginId); }
    [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Login)]
    public void UnSuccessfulLogin(string loginId){ WriteEvent(2, loginId); }

    [Event(3, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Login)]
    public void Logout(string loginId) { WriteEvent(3, loginId); }

    [Event(4, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Billing)]
    public void BillAudit(string UserId, string Action, string VisitId, string BillingID, string Details) { WriteEvent(4, UserId, Action, VisitId, BillingID, Details); }

    private static XYZWebLog _log = new XYZWebLog();
    private XYZWebLog() {}
    public static XYZWebLog Log { get { return _log; } }
}
```

And then here is the config for the SemanticLogging-svc.exe :

```
 <!-- Sinks reference definitons used by this host to listen ETW events -->
```

```
<flatFileSink name="svcRuntime" fileName="Billing.log" >
  <sources>


    <eventSource name="XYZWebLog" level="Informational" matchAnyKeyword="4" />
  </sources>

  <eventTextFormatter header="----------"/>
</flatFileSink>

<flatFileSink name="loginLogs" fileName="Login-Logout.log" >
  <sources>
    <eventSource name="XYZWebLog" level="Informational" matchAnyKeyword="2" />
  </sources>
  <eventTextFormatter header="++++++++++"/>
</flatFileSink>
```

If I remove the "matchAnyKeyword", and set up the levels correctly, I can make the events go into different files -- I have tried "2" and "0x002", and other things around defining the custom event that I can think of.  I have searched online and studied what documentation I could find.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about SLAB. But I was able to use your sample and generate ETW events based on Keywords.

Here is the code.

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                XYZWebLog.Log.SuccessfulLogin("naveen");
                XYZWebLog.Log.BillAudit("naveen", "bought", "123", "123", "details");

            }
        }
    }

    public class XYZWebLog : EventSource
    {
        public class Keywords
        {
            public const EventKeywords Login = (EventKeywords)2;
            public const EventKeywords Billing = (EventKeywords)4;
        }

        [Event(1, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Login)]
        public void SuccessfulLogin(string loginId) { WriteEvent(1, loginId); }
        [Event(2, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Login)]
        public void UnSuccessfulLogin(string loginId) { WriteEvent(2, loginId); }

        [Event(3, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Login)]
        public void Logout(string loginId) { WriteEvent(3, loginId); }
![enter image description here][1]
        [Event(4, Level = EventLevel.Informational, Keywords = Keywords.Billing)]
        public void BillAudit(string UserId, string Action, string VisitId, string BillingID, string Details)
        {
            WriteEvent(4, UserId, Action, VisitId, BillingID, Details);
        }
        private static XYZWebLog _log = new XYZWebLog();
        private XYZWebLog() { }
        public static XYZWebLog Log { get { return _log; } }
    }
}
```

My tool of choice to viewing and controlling ETW events is [Perfview](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/tags/perfview/)

I was able to generate events based on the keyword using PerfView. 
[image: Keywords for the providers]

If you notice in the `Additional Providers` field I have used the keyword 
`*XYZWebLog:4` which means I want to filter only  `Billing` events.

And based on this setting, only these events are generated.

[image: Audit Events]

And I changed the setting to `*XYZWebLog:2` and here is my output

[image: Login Events]

Comment: Thanks Naveen for so much detail !!  -- I am using Perfview to test, but my goal is to get different events to different sinks, using the SemanticLogging-svc.exe  -- Your work does seem to confirm that the ETW class is ok -- what is strange to me is that I do not see the events like you do on my Perfview.

Comment: If I put an if (IsEnabled(EventLevel.Informational, Keywords.Login)) around one of the event methods for the login methods, the "IsEnabled" part fails for me.

Comment: Which window in perfview are you looking for your events? Did you check  Events window? Did you look for any exceptions?

Comment: Looking in the Events window.  I see the manifest, but no events.  I didn't see any exceptions.

Comment: What is the outcome with out keywords? Did that produce anything else? What did you enter in the additional providers textbox? IMO you should provide detailed information and what you have tried instead of me asking every question. This would help in answering questions.

Comment: If you read the original description - i said pretty clearly that i get the events without Keywords.  It would help if you read the original problem entirely.